# iPhone apps with HTML5 with google Maps

Tags: iphone, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a web app with google maps and i'm now looking to transfer it to an iPhone app, probably using phonegap as it allows html5 coding for phone apps.

My question is- will google maps display ok on an iphone app?

regards,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made a Taxi ordering app using HTML5 (PhoneGap). Problem with Google Map api was that it was very slow. We decided to use MapKit instead. Google maps looked fine though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you going to use HTML, google maps should run fine on iPhone. But if going to submit to the App Store it might be rejected or its going to be slow.

Comment: thanks guys. I'm asking as i'm basing this answer as the reason to go ahead with making my app for iPhone, and also buying a Mac in the process